# Storing Start values in Dymola Issues

Tags: matlab, simulink, modelica, dymola

Modelica/Dymola SMR Model Help:
Currently I am working with an SMR model that has been developed in a Dymola environment,
and I am able to simulate it in a simulink environment using the Dymola block with the IO
set up with reactivity and the feedwater pump speed as the inputs. The only oustanding issues
with the model is the initialization, which is causing it to have a longer run time in
simulink than it normally does in just the dymola environment. In order to solve this issue, I've
tried utilizing the "store start values" option for when it reaches a steady state. But when I
try to use this, the following error pops up which can be seen in the image below.

[image: Variable errors]

Does anyone have
any experience with this issue that you were able to resolve this?

Comment: What is SMR? Do you use Dymola, or do you use OpenModelica? All start values that could not be stored are for derivatives of another variable, not sure what that means though

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the "Save start values in model" in section "5.2.2 Variable browser interaction" within the full Dymola manual? It mentions a number of issues that could cause the above:

> There are some limitations for what parameters, initial values, and start guesses that can be saved in the model. The following cannot be saved with the Save Start Values in Model command:
> • Evaluated parameters
> • Final parameters
> • Concealed variables
> • Protected variables may cause problems, see above paragraph
> • Arrays of variables in arrays of components
> • Start guesses for derivatives, e.g. der(x)

According to your list of variables, it seems the variables are "Start guesses for derivatives, e.g. der(x)" from the list above, and are therefore excluded.

Comment: Additionally in many cases (the highest order) derivatives appear linearly in the equations, and thus their guess-values aren't that important.